# Checking the C++ version on my laptop

Tags: c++, linux

I am currently in a CS class where we use C++, and I run Linux on my laptop. So the problem is that I think I don't have the most up to date version of C++. I've read online for several commands to get the version and this is my result. Also my Linux version is 16.04, and I am compiling in my terminal

```
tom@TBT-XPS-13-9360:~/Documents/Subjects/CS/OOP$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There 
is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A 
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I don' know what part of this is my actual version of C++. If my version is not the most up to date, can someone please give me DETAILED instructions on how to do it. Still getting my Linux legs.

Comment: Well, you probably meant C++ compiler version

Comment: GCC 5.4.0 is from June 2016. You will be missing out on the latest C++17 features but I'm sure none of those features will be taught anyway yet. C++14 support is fine.

Comment: `std::cout << __cplusplus / 100 % 100 << '\n';`

Comment: You could update (or replace) your distribution with Ubuntu 17.10 in a few days, in october 2017.

Comment: Similarly, your version of *Ubuntu* and your version of *Linux* are different. Ubuntu is a *distribution* of GNU/Linux, meaning it provides a bunch of programs and configuration files and stuff. Linux is one of the components (depending on how you look at it, the primary component) of Ubuntu, but it has a different version number. This is relevant because there are other distributions of Linux, and they have different version numbers (or sometimes no version number).

Answer (score 21):

C++ version (Or usually called c++ standard) is different than compiler version.

`g++` is your compiler, and your current version is `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`

You can use different command to compile your program using different C++ version.

```
g++ -std=c++11 yourFile .....
g++ -std=c++14 yourFile .....
```

As mentioned in the comments, this version of compiler may not support c++17 features yet

Comment: You can use [this table](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) to see which version first introduces support for each new c++ feature.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command in terminal (for linux only)

```
cpp --version
```